# SQL Server 2012 stored procedure error Msg 102

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server Management Studio 2012. When I try to create a stored procedure and I execute it, it returns an error every time. I really can not figure out whats wrong.

For example:

```
use AdventureWorks2012
CREATE PROCEDURE test () SELECT * FROM [Sales].[SalesPerson]
```

and the error is :

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 1
>
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.*

even If I just write `CREATE PROCEDURE TEST`

It will return error ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What database do you use? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Have you even looked at the documentation for the syntax? I am presuming MS SQL server as i see the AdventureWorks db reference in your code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test 
as        
begin               
  SELECT * FROM [Sales].[SalesPerson]
end
go
```

You have to remove `()` if your procedure does not need parameters, and add `as`, optionally `begin-end` (it's more usable).

If you want to add parameters to your procedure in future:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test 
(
  @param1 int
)
as        
begin               
  SELECT * FROM [Sales].[SalesPerson]
  where id = @param1
end
go
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have `AS` keyword when creating procedure

```
use AdventureWorks2012
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test 
AS
SELECT * FROM [Sales].[SalesPerson]
GO
```

Additionally you can add `BEGIN and END` if you have multiple queries on it.

Comment: I just copy and paste what you wrote and see what happens
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/92037912/error.jpg
I really dont know, I just started this at school and I dont know what exactly I am doing.

Comment: the error says that `There is already an object named 'test' in the database` this means that your syntax is already correct but the problem is the object name `test` already exist on the database. try `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test` to make it more descriptive